# Using material-ui's APIs, how do I set a background image in the body?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to set a background image in the body of my web app using material-ui-next's CSS-in-JS, withStyles, or themes? I would like to avoid using an external CSS file if possible.

Answer (score 9):

You can inject css into the outer scope with "@global" using withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles"

```css
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Main from "./Main";

const styles = theme => ({
 "@global": {
  body: {
   backgroundImage: "url('/media/landing.jpg')",
   backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
   backgroundPosition: "center center",
   backgroundSize: "cover",
   backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
   height: "100%"
  },
  html: {
   height: "100%"
  },
  "#componentWithId": {
   height: "100%"
  }
 }
});

const App = () => {
 return (
  <Fragment>
   <CssBaseline />
   <Main />
  </Fragment>
 );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```